# same error message displaying on every condition in onpostexecute method in android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

If new user signups it should show "success" message and if user is already exists then it should show "fail" message but for all conditions somehow its showing `Error parsing JSON Please data Fill all the records` this message.

Also if user is new and he register for new account the db gets updated with his particular details but shows him error message, how can we solve this issue ? any suggestion or help? Following code checks the `mysql` db records (for exist and new users).

```
//SignupActivity.java
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public SignupActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String fullName = arg0[0];
      //  String userName = arg0[1];
        String passWord = arg0[1];
        String phoneNumber = arg0[2];
        String emailAddress = arg0[3];

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
        //    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
            data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
            data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

        //  link = "http://mangoair.in/MangoAir_User/mangoair_reg/insert.php" + data;

          link = "http://hostogen.com/mangoair10/tryr.php" + data;

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON Please data Fill all the records.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

//insert.php
        <?php
                                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","hosto4p7_hosto","hostogen123","hosto4p7_hostogen");
                                   // This code checks if the user already exists or not and send to above code for further queries like displaying messages

                                    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                                    {
                                       echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
                                    }

                                    $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
                                    //$userName = $_GET['username'];
                                    $passWord = $_GET['password'];
                                    $phoneNumber = $_GET['phonenumber'];
                                    $emailAddress = $_GET['emailaddress'];


                                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users10 WHERE phone='$phoneNumber' OR email='$emailAddress'";

                                                $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

                                                if(isset($check)){
                                                      echo '{"query_result":"FAIL"}';
                                                }
                                                            else{               
                                                     $sql = "INSERT INTO users10 (fullname,password,phone,email) VALUES('$fullName','$passWord','$phoneNumber','$emailAddress')";

                                                                     $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                                                                     if($result == true) {
                                                                     echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
                                                                }
                                                               else{
                                                                      echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
                                                                   }
                                                           }
                                                           mysqli_close($con);


                              ?>
```

Comment: what is `jsonStr` in onPostExecute? Try to log it and check using `Log.d`

Comment: The problem is you're not parsing JSON correctly, investigate in this direction.

Comment: jsonStr is a string variable  i.e. String jsonStr = result;

Comment: Whatever json you are getting, first chk it is a Valid JSOn or not ! Use (www.jsonlint.com). Also post your json here, such that we can chk, whether you are extracting the JSONObject properly or not !